# Why do we need epsilon-transitions in Thompson's construction?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, simulation

So as learned every DFA is an NFA. I feel like I understand DFA much better than NFA, so I try to convert my regular expressions to DFA, but I want to understand both sides.

For example a|b (a Union b):

[image: From Sipser]
[image: Generated by http://hackingoff.com/, example of NFA a|b]

However, are we losing anything if we eliminate the epsilon from these expressions, every DFA is an NFA right so what are we losing if we don't include it?

[image: Generated by http://hackingoff.com/, example of DFA a|b]

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "Every DFA is an NFA." The automata in your question are NFAs, so you need the converse. But the converse is weaker: every NFA can be converted to a DFA.

Comment: The questioner can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the subtext was "we're constructing an NFA, so why don't we just construct a DFA because that's also an NFA".

Comment: Sorry I wanted to post a comparable DFA however since I am new I am only allowed to provide up to 2 links

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking at there is what's known as Thompson's construction. The idea is that any node in the regular expression parse tree corresponds to an NFA with a single entry and exit point. To see why the epsilon transitions are useful, try applying the construction to, say, $(a \cup b^*)c$.

Thompson's construction is particularly easy to understand and implement but it is also, as you rightly say, a bit wasteful. It is possible to construct Thompson's automaton with the epsilon transitions removed using [Glushkov's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov%27s_construction_algorithm). You may also be interested in [Xing's construction](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/xing2004.pdf).